# How to execute a js function based on url hash url#nameoffunction

Tags: javascript, function, hash

I saw some of websites executes a JavaScript function based on has in the URL. For example,

when I access http://domain.com/jobs#test

then the website executes a function based on #test

I can do it by checking location.href, but is there a better way?

Comment: You asked right question friend (y)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what i do:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var hash = (window.location.hash).replace('#', '');
    if (hash.length == 0) {
        //no hash do something
    }
    else {
        //else do something with hash
    }
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/XCjpy/show/#test
demo2: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/XCjpy/show/
demo3: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/XCjpy/show/#testing_again

Comment: You saved me friend (y)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to support old browsers like IE6 and IE7 you can use:

```
window.onhashchange = function(){
  switch(location.hash) {
    case '#hash1':
      //do something
    break;
    case '#has2':
      //do something else
    break;
  }
}
```

But if you have to support older browsers you need to poll:

```
var oldHash = location.hash;
setInterval(function(){
  if(location.hash !== oldHash){
    oldHash = location.hash;
    //hash changed do something
  }
}, 120);
```

Comment: // Thank you for the input. I didn't know there is such event, but..what I want to do is execute a function upon onload or domready by checking hash tag. I tested it out, but onhashchange doesn't fire when i access a url with hash tag attached. I appreciate your input though.

Comment: What you could do is set a function `hashChanged` that you use for `window.onhashchange = hashChanged`. And you call the same function `hashChanged()` in a `script` tag at the very end of the `body` tag

Answer (score 2):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rq5G2/)**

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
    var hash = document.location.hash;
    var func = hash.replace('#', '');
    eval(func + '()');
});

function asdf() {
    alert('asdf function');
}

function qwerty() {
    alert('qwerty function');
}
```

**Note:** `eval()` is dangerous. You **should** make a predefined array of safe functions, and call those.

Comment: Put an `eval` in the answer, and then tell not to use it? Nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location).

See the property table.
location.hash should help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library like YUI to do this more elegantly, Take a look at the YUI Browser History Manager

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/history/