# Execute a javascript function depending on url?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the css of a div depending on the url you are at.

Here is the code I came up with...

```
<script>
if (window.location.href == "http://www.example.com/?tab-1") {
    function(){ 
        $('body').css('color','red !important');
    }
}
</script>
```

Could someone explain how properly execute a function based on the current url?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076576/how-to-execute-a-js-function-based-on-url-hash-urlnameoffunction

Comment: But you're not executing the function...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

    var tab = window.location.href.split('?')[1]; // tab-1
    if(tab){
      $('body').addClass( tab );
    }

});
```

than in your **CSS**:

```
.tab-1{
   background: red ;  /* add !important if needed */
}
.tab-2{
   background: blue ; /* add !important if needed */
}
```

[demo concept](http://jsbin.com/IwireQu/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

To execute a different function based on what comes after the question mark on a url (taking the question at face value) you can use this:

```
var functions = {
    "tab-1": function() {
        //do tab-1 stuff
    },

    "tab-2": function() {
        //do tab-2 stuff
    }
}

$(function() {
    var qs = location.search;
    if (qs.length > 0) {
        var func = functions[qs.substring(1)]
        if ($.isFunction(func)) func();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should call `window.onload` so that you catch the url when its entered and trigger the action that you want (in this case a css change) inmediately.

```
function changecss() {
    if (window.location.href == "http://www.example.com/?tab-1") {
        function(){ 
            $('body').css('color','red !important');
        }
    }

}

window.onload = changecss;
```