# How do I create a link to a page and force it to immediately execute a javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to open a specific view of a website. In fact the webpage is only one page and the links on the page execute javascript functions to change the visible content. My question is:

How can I create a link to this webpage that tells the page which javascript function to be executed in order for it to show the desired page view?

Comment: You can't "force" a script to be executed through simply a link. It would be extremely dangerous. What you can do though is pass some info (ex: function name, JSON...) through queries, and the target page can grab that and do what you want. Or if both windows have the same origin, you can simply access the target `window` and directly execute scripts.

Comment: You can add a hash to the links targeting to the site. You can then check for a specific hash in the onload-Event of your site and fire the javascript you want to set up this view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076576/how-to-execute-a-js-function-based-on-url-hash-urlnameoffunction

Comment: @mwoelk This sounds like a good solution which does not need a complete redesign of the target webpage.

Comment: @Roope And this even tells us how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting modern browsers, you may use `postMessage` to send messages between windows.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

You could be listening for messages on your main window while your popup send them.